# How to pass the value of input type radio in application_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an admin template, and there is a customizer section in which I have created 3 radio buttons (named: Red, Blue, Green). There is a left sidebar navigation menu and I want to change the background color of sidebar navigation menu by clicking on the radio buttons.
If I am clicking on the button it is changing the bg-color of sidebar navigation menu by adding a class, but if I am going to another page gets reloaded and the class gets removed.

I have tried one thing, in my application_helper.rb I have added the following code

```
    def is_active(action)
        @color = "red"
        params[:action] == action_name ? @color : nil                  
      end
```

and in my layouts folder, I have a partial file _sidebar.html.erb and at the outer div I am using this helper like below

```
    <div class="sidebar-nav <%= is_active('action_name') %>" id="collapse-sidebar"  >
```

What I am doing here is, checking the action name if it is matching then adding a class red which is stored in an instance variable @color

If I can pass the value of the radio button to the application_helper file dynamically means if I click on red the value should be red, green then the value should be green. and by which I can change the class name dynamically in application helper and further that would change the color of the sidebar.

Please, If I am doing anything wrong or it's is not the right way to do this or we can't achieve this kind of functionality in ruby on rails, please acknowledge me, that would be appreciable.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding you, but instance variables get lost between requests, so there's no point on using `@color` instead of `red`.

If you want to *persist* `red` over requests then store it in the session or pass it as a param.

Comment: Thanks, It  helps to store the value in a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly reframing your sidebar code:

```
<div class="sidebar-nav <%= selected_color(params[:action]) %>" id="collapse-sidebar"  >
```

Assuming you are passing color names('Red', 'Blue' or 'Green') in the `action` parameter, the `application_helper.rb` code would go like this:

```
def selected_color(action_color_name)
  colors = ['Red','Blue', 'Green']
  colors.include? action_color_name ? action_color_name : nil                  
end
```

Also, store `action` in a hidden variable so that, colors will retain upon going to some other page. If that doesn't work, simply store the `sidebar_color` in configurations table in the database and update the attribute upon clicking respective radio buttons.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Basically the main thing I want to do is when I click on any radio button the value of the button should pass as a parameter in action, suppose if I click on red the params value should be red if green then it should be green and on the basis of that I want to change the name of class, so wheneven i click on any radio button this will change the color of sidebar dynamically, But I don't know how to pass the values of radio button.

Comment: I am providing you a link, open it and there is a button on the right side with setting icon and its being rotating, click on that, and there would be a sidebar filter if you click on any radio button it will change the sidebar background color, but its in vuejs so the color won't  change if you go to another page.please open the link and you will get the idea.

http://vuely.theironnetwork.org/default/dashboard/ecommerce

Comment: Pass the `action` variable in form and submit the form on radio button click. Refer this link on how to submit a form on radio button click: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846526/submitting-rails-form-on-a-radio-button-selection?]

Comment: ok, but where to submit the form , to application_helper.rb ?

Comment: Firstly please tell me that did you open the link and checked that functionality of changing the color of the sidebar, Is it really possible?